# SetWindowText not changing alt-tab title depending on theme

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, windows-7

While running Windows 7 in Windows Classic theme:

I have a CDialog where I am setting the title bar text and icon as

```
SetWindowText(_dialog->GetSafeHwnd(), "Example Name");
_dialog->SetIcon(AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME), TRUE);
```

This is correctly reflected in the Windows taskbar and in the alt-tab menu.

However in another CDialog the change is only completely showing in the taskbar: alt-tab has the changed icon, but no title text.

The title is not being set elsewhere.

If I then switch to an Aero theme, the titles correctly appear in the alt-tab menu. Switching back to Classic will show the title in the alt-tab menu, provided I had tabbed into them.

I'm not sure why they're behaving differently in different themes.

Comment: [The secret life of GetWindowText](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030821-00/?p=42833). Also: [Why are the rules for GetWindowText so weird?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030904-00/?p=42663)

Comment: BTW: it's unwise to use identifiers that start with a `_` (such as `_dialog`).

Comment: If you are talking about a `CFrameWnd` derived class, you may need to override the `OnUpdateFrameTitle` on it, because `CDocument` may be actively changing its window text. My suggestion is to implement the override, which only calls its `super::` counterpart and put a breakpoint in that call, to see what is happening by looking to the call stack.